# How to set picture as whatsapp or contact photo profile picture

Tags: android

I displayed images from webservice using json. Now how to provide user to make image as profile picture for whatsapp or contact photo etc., How to call that intent to open set picture as -> Set as -> showing multiple options -> Contact photo wallpaper, whatsapp profile photo etc.,?

Please guide me to solve this..

Thanks

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231111/how-to-set-profile-photo-option-in-android?rq=1